# How to create regular expression extractor in jmeter

Tags: regex, jmeter

I am trying to extract the location from a POST in jmeter using the Regex Expression Extractor. The header looks like the below

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
groopId: ID-99-Inc-07-12300-2650126876118-1-236
User-Agent: RestClient-Tool
Date: Thu, 14 Feb 2019 13:57:23 GMT
Location: v2/TestData/12sff-13343e-dff3444455
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
```

I need the`Location: v2/TestData/12sff-13343e-dff3444455` .

[image]

I am struggling because I am not quite sure how to create the regex I need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Comment: @Biffen your link is useful, but it's not really a duplicate...

Comment: But it is a dupe of [What do 'lazy' and 'greedy' mean in the context of regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions) (after adding the screenshot showing what the real problem is)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew tbh honest it was a bit of confirmation of asking how to use the regular expression extractor in Jmeter and confirming whether the regex was correct

Comment: You can confirm at http://regex101.com - it explains all the regex patterns automatically and in great detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) as a child of the request which returns above headers
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Apply to: depending on where this [Location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Location) header comes from
   - Field to check: `Response Headers`
   - Regular Expression: `Location: (.*)`
   - Template: `$1$`

     [image]
3. That's it, you should be able to access the extracted value as `${location}` where required.

References:

- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)

Comment: ah I was so close!! thanks for your answer @Dmitri T